# How to intercept static methods in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, aop, interceptor

Subject line basically says it all. I have a static method I want to intercept so that around advice can be applied to it. I can get this to work with any non-static methods but I'm unsure how to allow static methods to be intercepted.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't do that with Spring AOP, because it is proxy based. You have to use AspectJ. Take a look at this simple example: http://blog.jayway.com/2007/02/16/static-mock-using-aspectj/

Answer (score -2):

See PowerMock https://github.com/powermock/powermock
it can mock static methods

Taken from the blog post comment from LIMC's answer

Comment: That is a testing tool. My case was for a production use. So Powermock is not appropriate there.  limc was correct in suggesting AspectJ.