# Using aspects to hijack static methods of classes from different servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets, aspectj

## The background

I try to use [LightAdmin](http://lightadmin.org/) in my Spring application. The root problem I have is, that it only supports some base plain types - I use `java.util.UUID` for example, which is not supported ([see here](https://github.com/la-team/light-admin/blob/1.0.0.M2/lightadmin-core/src/main/java/org/lightadmin/core/persistence/metamodel/DomainTypeAttributeType.java)).

Since these are static methods and there is no really any POI to bind own types, I thought about using aspects for that.

## The problem

But that araised another problem - I can't make my aspect to hijack this static call. LightAdmin works as a separate servlet, but in the same application and my aspect is loaded in `applicationContext.xml`.

`TypeHandler.java` (the aspect code):

```java
@Aspect
public class TypeHandler
{
    @Before("execution(static * org.lightadmin.core.persistence.metamodel.DomainTypeAttributeType.forType(..))")
    public void myBefore()
    {
        System.out.println("HIJACKED!");
    }
}
```

`applicationContext.xml` fragments:

```xml
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<context:component-scan
    base-package="my.website.web.backend"
    use-default-filters="true"
>
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect"/>
</context:component-scan>
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

I use *Tomcat7* with `org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader` class loader.

In log I can see:

```
...
11:02:55.198 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver - Using a reflective load-time weaver for class loader: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader
...
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'backend'
11:03:11.677 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'backend': initialization started
11:03:11.687 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'backend-servlet': startup date [Fri Aug 08 11:03:11 CEST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
11:03:11.689 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/backend-servlet.xml]
11:03:11.770 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'backend': initialization completed in 93 ms
sie 08, 2014 11:03:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'lightadmin-dispatcher'
11:03:11.772 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'lightadmin-dispatcher': initialization started
11:03:11.773 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'lightadmin-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Aug 08 11:03:11 CEST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
...
```

(`/WEB-INF/backend-servlet.xml` is empty)

And application fails after calling `org.lightadmin.core.persistence.metamodel.DomainTypeAttributeType.forType()` for my UUID field without being hijacked by my aspect.

I already tried adding `@Component` annotation, registering the bean by hand in `applicationContext.xml` etc. - makes no effect. At all I think that the aspect itself is being loaded by beans factory, because if I configure an invalid pointcut, I have an exception about that.

## The question(s)

So my two questions are:

1. Is there other way to make this working (without LightAdmin source code modification, I want to avoid that at all costs)?
2. If no, then how to make this aspect working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the latest redesigned [LightAdmin](https://github.com/la-team/light-admin) version with an extended set of supported types (**UUID**, **Joda-Time**). It's upgraded to Spring 4.0.X, the newest Spring DATA/REST and contains a bunch of defect fixes.

BTW, you don't need to use LightAdmin Nexus repositories anymore for releases. 
It's available directly from Maven Central now.

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP cannot be used for static methods. You will have to use full AspecJ for that use. You can find another reference for that in [How to intercept static methods in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993947/how-to-intercept-static-methods-in-spring).

You have no exception when defining the pointcut, because its syntax is valid in AspectJ, simply it cannot be processed by Spring AOP.