# Unable to configure Spring AOP with Gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to log exception using SpringBoot and AOP. Using gradlew and Java 1.8.

Main.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {

@Override
public void run(String... args) {
    try{
    ThrowingExample();
    }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("This message is printed");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
}

static void ThrowingMethod() throws FileNotFoundException {
  throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
}
```

AfterThrowAspect.java

```
@Component("AfterThrowAspect")
@Aspect
public class AfterThrowAspect {

  @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* *.*.*(..))", throwing = "exception")
  public void logAfterThrowing(Exception exception) {
    System.out.println("Not Printed @AfterReturning:"+new Date());
    System.out.println("Exception caught:"+ exception.getMessage());**
  }

}
```

My Gradle File is

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'idea'

mainClassName = 'learn.Main'

repositories {
   maven  {
    url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
   }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

configurations {
  aspectjweaver
}

dependencies {
   compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
   testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
   exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.+"
compile "org.springframework:spring-aop:4.+"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.+"
compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.+"
compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.+"

aspectjweaver "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.+"
runtime configurations.aspectjweaver.dependencies
}
```

Method logAfterThrowing is never called after exception. I am using Intellj and ide says ThrowingMethod is AdvisedMethod.

I am new to Java. Looking around on web makes me feel this should work but not happening. It compiles and run but logAfterThrowing from AfterThrowAspect.java never called. All files are on same hierarchy and same package.

Comment: I think your code looks fine, maybe it is something with the Gradle configuration. I just played around with Spring + Aspects + Gradle a little bit and have my result on GitHub. You can have a look at it and maybe adjust your `build.gradle`: https://github.com/rieckpil/sample-spring5-microservice

Comment: Did you check `AfterThrowAspect ` component initialized?

Comment: @Zico i do not see i startup log. So i guess not initialized. Will update if able to do it.

Comment: @Zico though i do not see component loaded in log, but appContext.containsBeanDefinition("AfterThrowAspect") return true. I edited my post for component to have name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT
>
> I think I have found the problem with your code. Spring aspect-oriented programming will only work with beans that are maintained by spring container. **Since the method throwing the exception is a static method there is no way spring can intercept this**.

[How to intercept static methods in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993947/how-to-intercept-static-methods-in-spring)

> Solution

**Define your method in a service or a component and autowire it.**

Working example repo https://github.com/mirmdasif/springmvc/tree/master/aopexceptionhandling

> Complete Answer

**First**, define your method in a service bean

```
@Service
public class ExceptionalService {
    public void thorowException() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

**Second**, Instead of `@component` annotation, you should use `@configuration` in your AspectJ class. Also, use proper package name in pointcut

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class ErrorInterceptor {
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* net.asifhossain.*.*(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void errorInterceptor(Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Third** Autowire the service and use it.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AopExampleApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ExceptionalService service;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        try {
            service.thorowException();
            thorowException();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Do nothing Since aop will log the answer
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AopExampleApp.class);
    }

    public static void thorowException() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

I have created a blog post with complete step by step procedure of how we can handle exception using Spring's Aspect Oriented Programming.
You can access it at the following link

[Handling Exception Using Spring AOP](https://javarockzz.blogspot.com/2018/01/handling-exception-using-springs-aspect.html)

Comment: Tried with proper package name in pointcut and changed annotation did not helped. My IDE is able to get methods on which aspect would be applied, so i guess pointcut was good.

Comment: Let me share my repository with working solution in a minute

Comment: @VishalKumar I have updated my answer and also added an example in github see if this works. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for response. It worked when i make ExceptionalService spring service. But '@Component' annotation suffices for ErrorInterceptor. No need for '@Configuration'.